# set UIImageView property from a method called by another method

Tags: objective-c

(newbie Q, asking after a full day research)

Kindly help, where am I going wrong :

I can set an `UIImageView` property successfully from `viewDidLoad` : `[TodayMark setHidden:YES];`

But it does not work when I put it in aother instance method (in the same class) and call that method from `viewDidLoad`.

The method itself is getting called fine but only the property does not get set and I get no error or warning !

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  ...
        [TodayMark setHidden:NO];    // This is working fine

        //calling the instance method

    myClass *test = [[myClass alloc] init];
    [test WeekName]; 

}

-(void)WeekName{

    NSLog(@"---test call---");  // getting printed in the consol
    [TodayMark setHidden:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self`, and you do not need to `alloc/init` a new instance there, just use `self` and everything will be groovy.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    //...
    [TodayMark setHidden:NO];
    [self WeekName]; 
}
```

And...

```
-(void) WeekName {
    NSLog(@"---test call---");
    [TodayMark setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: AMAZING Jacob! you are the groovy person here, many thx for your prompt reply, the problem is fixed.